# How to get exception details from MVC3 ajax call

Tags: asp.net, ajax, exception, asp.net-mvc-3

I use ASP.NET MVC 3 with Razor and Ajax.ActionLink/BeginForm to update Partial Views. When there is a server-side exception, how to get and display exception details in the browser?

Thanks

Comment: Are you handling any exceptions in your app by using HandleError? Else if you are looking to capture a specific exception, in the catch block you can dump in the exception details in the TempData and access it in the redirected page. http://www.gregshackles.com/2010/07/asp-net-mvc-do-you-know-where-your-tempdata-is/

Comment: Looks like I wasn't clear with the question, but found what I was looking for:


`code`    function ajaxCallFailed(ajaxContext) {
        alert(ajaxContext._response._xmlHttpRequest.response);
    }

Answer (score -1):

You need to do 2 things: first create a filter in which you will set the result in the filterContext with the piece of information you want to display. Second, you will need a piece of client code to handle the response. You can do this via jQuery $.ajaxError.

You could also create a specific controller and a view for more complicated scenarii. This is described here:

http://christopheargento.com/2011/08/18/unifier-les-remontees-dexception-ajax-et-non-ajax-en-asp-net-mvc-3/

It is in french but there is a demo and downloadable code. If you need more information you can ask me.

EDIT: Finally the english version of the article is released: http://blog.christopheargento.net/2012/06/14/unify-exception-handling-between-ajax-and-non-ajax-requests-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. This is especially important for this answer given that it is in French.

Comment: Sorry I assumed that source code provided was sufficient to solve the problem even with the wrong language.

Comment: That's not really the point. If you're posting a link to an outside source then you **must** summarise the content of the article explaining why and how it solves the problem the OP is having. Otherwise if the site goes down the link rots and is of no use to future users of the site who have the same problem. Otherwise this answer will need to be removed.

Comment: Ok I get it. I edited the answer with a few more information.